# Serve static file with React JS

Tags: reactjs, admob, jhipster

I am using React JS (that comes with JHipster) to serve my website. Now I am integrating Google Admob which requires me to add `app-ads.txt` to the website. I played around with the existing code when I needed to add new pages such `privacy` and `terms` however they contain decorations (header / footer).

However when I tried to introduce new path `app-ads.txt` it just show `Your request cannot be processed`.

Example

```
const Routes = () => (
  <div className="view-routes">
    <Switch>
      <ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/logout" component={Logout}/>
      <PrivateRoute path="/admin" component={Admin} hasAnyAuthorities={[AUTHORITIES.ADMIN]}/>
      <ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/terms" exact component={Terms}/>
      <ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/privacy" exact component={Privacy}/>
      <ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/app-ads.txt" exact component={AppAds}/> // not working
      <ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/" exact component={HomeNew}/>
      <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Entities} hasAnyAuthorities={[AUTHORITIES.USER]}/>
      <ErrorBoundaryRoute component={PageNotFound}/>
    </Switch>
  </div>
);
```

and

```
import React from 'react';

export const AppAds = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      google.com, pub-24159654231069759, DIRECT, f08c47asdec0942fa0
    </div>
  );
};
```

The idea is when user hits `mydomainexample/app-ads.txt` my website should only return its content without any decorations (header / footer).

It *kinda* work when I changed the new path with `app-ads` (without `.txt`) however the displayed content has decorations which I don't want.

Comment: Don't add it to the router, just put it in the _public_ directory which is used for serving static files.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer @MattClark! I updated the `CopyWebpackPugin` my `webpack.common.js` with `{ from: './src/main/webapp/app-ads.txt', to: 'app-ads.txt' }` to get it working